# Why this is buggin in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I made a website: http://www.saborearte.pt/

I don't know why the website has a bug in IE, I've tryed some workarrounds but i don't find the CSS error.

**Why i can't resolve it?**
1- I'm using Mac.
2- Internet Explorer doesn't have a nice **Developer Tools**

### ** EDIT: **

```
    <div id="headercloth"></div>
    <header id="header" class="clearfix"> 
        <div class="wrap"> 
            <div id="logo" class="left"> 
                <a href="http://www.saborearte.pt"> 
                    Sabor&Arte
                    <img src="assets/images/estilo/logos/logo.png" height="145" width="217" alt="Sabor&Arte Logo" /> 
                </a> 
            </div> 
            <div id="nav"> 
                <nav class="jquery-menu clearfix sombra"> 
                        <ul><li class="active"><a href="http://www.saborearte.pt/" title="Quem Somos" >Quem Somos</a></li> 
<li><a href="/galeria" title="Galeria" >Galeria</a></li> 
<li><a href="/ementa" title="Ementa" >Ementa</a></li> 
<li class="last"><a href="/contactos" title="Contactos" >Contactos</a></li> 
</ul> 
                </nav> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </header>
```

this code snippet **isn't rendering** correctly on **IE** (6 , 7 and 8)

Comment: Can you please post the code that's causing issue?

Comment: What's the specific error? How is it expected to look, and how does Internet Explorer differ from this? What versions of IE cause this problem?

Comment: You have to be more specific, both about what bug you are talking about, and what version of IE that you are using to test it. I checked the page in Firefox and IE 9, and I couldn't see any difference at all.

Comment: Troubleshooting and steps-to-repro. Learn them. They will serve you well.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.saborearte.pt%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: both versions, 7, 8 and 9 (i think)

the problem is on the CSS i think, try to open it at firefox or chrome and then on internet explorer. My problems are: i work on Mac, and Internet Explorer doesn't have a decent developer tools

Comment: @Quentin, the errors or warnings showed by w3 aren't the problem

Comment: Can we reopen this? I know what the problem is.

Comment: Edited, if someone can help me, please, reopen and answer. Thanks

Comment: The site is html5 - you need to feed the new html5 tags to ie8 on load so he understands them. Try http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/

Comment: He provided the website link - all code is there - what is the problem with you guys?

Comment: "I'm using Mac." — VMWare is lovely (and VirtualBox is cheap).
"Internet Explorer doesn't have a nice Developer Tools" — it has acceptable ones now.

Comment: I do have Parallels Desktop, but i have only IE 9 instaled, to test at 8 and 7 i use another computer :)

Comment: @CuSS: Using IE9, hit F12 (to bring up the Developer Tools), and change the Browser Mode. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE version 8 and lower do not natively recognize unknown elements.

For some background details: http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

> ..however in practice, Internet Explorer
>   6-8 pose a problem as they do not
>   recognize unknown elements; the new
>   elements cannot hold children and are
>   unaffected by CSS.

The fix is as simple as including this in your page, in your `<head>`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

For further instructions: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: @CuSS: I have to say, if you'd just included a snippet of your HTML in the question in the first place, this would have been answered instantly instead of being closed.

Comment: an alternative to the html5shiv mentioned in the answer is Modernizr.

Comment: Thanks, it worked nicely. Internet Explorer is an Headache to me :)

Comment: @thirtydot - Users on SO are way to aggressive - sometimes if you read the question twice you realize that it actually has enough data in it to debug.

Comment: i understand, their problem is that if i don't post the bad code, after correction, the link will not last forever. (sorry my bad english)

Comment: @spudley Modernizr uses same script as html5shiv. Just the load is bigger.

Comment: @easwee - My experience was that Modernizr worked for us, while html5shiv didn't. I don't know why, and I didn't take the time to investigate further. Also, Modernizr provides additional functionality which is useful (especially for dealing with IE). Finally, the most recent version of Modernizr allows you to reduce it's footprint by only including the features you want.

Comment: @Spudley - can't argue on that - but if you check the documentation it states that it uses the same identical script since version 1.5.